# Changing the value of a qtip tooltip on click (jquery)

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I have a link with a tooltip (qtip). On toggle it adds a quick link on the page. If I click it again it removes the quick link. So far so good. However I'd like to change the text of the data-tooltip on toggle as well (from "add quick link" to "remove quick link")

This is what I've got so far:

```
<a class="add-link" data-tooltip="add quick link"></a>
```

jquery:

```
$('.add-link').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-tooltip', 'add quick link')) {
        $(this).attr('data-tooltip', 'remove quick link');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('data-tooltip', 'add quick link');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("added");
});
```

css:

```
a.add-link {
   content: '+';
}

a.add-link.added {
  content: '-';
```

}

It toggles the class correctly, however the text in the qtip tooltip does not change. Have searched on SO and the qtip API but can't make this work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: i dont see any line in making the text change

Comment: Did you enable the qtip cache?

Comment: @guradio the text change is in the if/else condition.

Comment: @JuniorOliveira, no didn't know I had too, will look it up.

Comment: @WimMertens, I was actually trying to say "disable", sorry. I did a little search at the qtip source code and seems that they use cache by default,  you'll probably need to access it and disable, try: QTip.cache.disabled = TRUE (This will probably have performance issues)

Comment: @JuniorOliveira I'll give that a go, thanks!

Comment: http://qtip2.com/options#content.text you can do content text as a function and return $(this).attr('data-tooltip'); /* or $(this).data('tooltip'); */

Comment: @smcd thanks but this doesn't say anything about changing it on click or I must have skipped over it...

Comment: @JuniorOliveira disabling cache didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: When the data-tooltip is updated by your above code it would be changed on next appearance of the tooltip if set up like $('a').qtip({content:{text:function(event,api) { return $(this).data('tooltip');}}}); The code you have above though will always make it be 'remove quick link' on click.

Comment: Thanks, will fiddle around with this. No luck so far though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but you have to move mouse off and back over the anchor to see it changed after clicking.

```js
$('.add-link').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-tooltip') === 'add quick link') { /* fixup */
    $(this).attr('data-tooltip', 'remove quick link');
  } else {
    $(this).attr('data-tooltip', 'add quick link');
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("added");
});

/* '.add-link' instead of 'a' if you like, or 'a.add-link' */
$('a').qtip({
  content: {
    text: function(event, api) {
      return $(this).attr('data-tooltip')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/basic/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/basic/jquery.qtip.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="add-link" data-tooltip="add quick link" href="#">I am an anchor...</a>
<br>Click link &amp; move mouse out and back over to see tooltip changed
```

Comment: The **cache: false,** that was in the qtip options did nothing, forgot to take it out earlier.